# How to create a auto complete text field in symfony with AbstractType Form?

Tags: php, git, symfony, doctrine-orm, autocomplete

I am trying to create a auto complete text field in symfony with AbstractType Form which gets data from database and I want it to give me suggestions on whatever I enter as input , I have tried several third party plugins for that but its not working , may be i have missed some installation procedure .
here are the [link](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXAutoCompleterBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) of plugin i have used form git
 after following the complete installation steps it gives me plain text field.
is there any other way to create a auto complete text box ,
here is my code for FormType

```
 $builder->add('autoText', 'autocomplete', array(
     'class' => 'MyBundle:Demo',
 ));
```

my **html.twig** template:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    [{% for auto in results -%}
        {{ {id: auto.id, label: auto.name, value: auto.name}|json_encode|raw }}
        {%- if not loop.last %},{% endif -%}
    {%- endfor %}]
</div>

<!-- js -->

{% javascripts
    'js/jquery.js'
    'js/jquery-ui.js'
    '@PUGXAutocompleterBundle/Resources/public/js/autocompleter-jqueryui.js'
%}
{% endjavascripts %}
{% javascripts %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#autoText').autocompleter({url_list: '/auto_search', url_get: '/auto_get/'});
    </script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

my **DemoController**

```
Public class DemoController extends Controller{
//....
    public function searchAutoAction(Request $request) {
        $q = $request->get('AutoText');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $results = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Demo')->findLikeName($q);

        return array('results' => $results);
    }
    public function getAutoAction($id) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $auto = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Demo')->find($id);

        return new Response($auto->getName());
    }

.....//
}
```

**route.yml**

```
auto_search:
    path: /auto_search/
    defaults: { _controller:MyBundle:Demo:searchAuto }

auto_get:
    path: /auto_get/
    defaults: { _controller:MyBundle:Demo:getAuto }
```

Comment: have you checked from your page source that the created form input id matches the one that you are using in your javascript? I.e. that the id actually is 'autoText'...

Comment: yes , i have checked it form my page source , the id is same ,

Comment: i have also tried '{{ form_row(form.autoText) }}' to render on html , result is same in both condition

Comment: @TusharPurohit What result are you receiving? What is showing the browser console?

Comment: should your auto_get route match with the function definition that you have visible here? auto_get is using getAutoAction whereas you have getFormulaAction defined... if console doesn't show anything, how about the network activity? can you see whether there are any jquery calls when you type something in the text field?

Comment: console does'nt shows anything , no error are there , i am receiving a plain text field in ui instead of an auto complete  box.

Comment: @ejuhjav :  thats typo , i have corrected it .

Comment: is there any other way to create a auto complete text field , or any other plugin that works,

Answer (score 0):

Read this [doc page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html), and add js libraries like this:

```
{% javascripts
    'js/jquery.js'
    'js/jquery-ui.js'
    '@PUGXAutocompleterBundle/Resources/public/js/autocompleter-jqueryui.js'
%}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Comment: OK , i have added that assetic path for jqury and jquery-ui , but still the result is same. its just a text field.

Comment: yes i have read the document and i have used all the asset according the instruction give there .

Comment: @TusharPurohit Are the libraries being included? Can you check the html source code?

Comment: @TusharPurohit If all is OK, and controller actions also are OK, but code is still not working, may be there are some errors on browser console? Can you post the generated html code of the form?